# notepad++ , theme/Style configurator

Tags: themes, notepad++

In notepad++ i downloaded a theme , and i am customizing it at the moment, but i can't seem to find how to change the color of the ... ( i don't actually know how it's called ... )

[image]

As you see i have the  tag selected , what i am interested in changing is this light green thats on "src=images/menu.js" and "id=relativeMenu" and " alt="" "
Any idea how do i do that or maybe how is the highlighting called.

Comment: I haev just written a notepad++ theme RANDOM GENERATOR :DDD its a page it runs in unity3d compiler at the moment but it can generate 1000ds of templates from one template which is faster than searching online and DLing them, yuo have to specify roughly the brughtness of bg and fg and it will generate the random colors, you can change the code to add some random saturation and value on top of the base values which are the brightness darkness preferences. Thanks. search online for random notepad theme gen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the "Tags Attribute" style, it's under "Global Styles" -> "Tags Attribute"